# How to write Expressions in SOQL Query

Tags: soql, query, queryexception, expressions

I have a custom object Professor

```
Professor { Name(Text) , Salary(Number) , Bonus(Number)}
```

I wrote the query in Developer console

```
select Name from Professor__c where (salary__c + bonus__c) > 7
```

and got below error

```
Unknown error parsing query:
Professor__c where (salary__c + bonus__c) > 7 ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:57 unexpected token: ')'
```

How to write expression in SOQL WHERE and SELECT clauses?

Comment: you cannot write any expressions in query.

Comment: @TariqueShamim does this limitation apply to apex code also.. (i mean query rewritten from apex code)

Comment: Yes @DineshKumar

Comment: You may have to create an extra field on the same object which store's the sum of Salary and Bonus and then you can use that field to add a condition in SOQL query.

Comment: Either you can create a formula field to hold the sum of those fields
Or
You can query the records, iterate and form a new one where those two fields sum is greater than 7.

Comment: @TariqueShamim - you should write this as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SOQL query you are not allowed to mix expression in where clause.
What you can add here is, you can create an extra **formula field** of type **number** which will have the sum of Salary__c and Bonus__c field value and then you can use the new field to compare.

Let's say the new field is **Gross__c** having formula (**Salary__c + Bonus__c**)
Now you can use it in query,

```
SELECT Name FROM Professor__c WHERE Gross__c > 7
```